# Space around escaped equations in listings?

Tags: spacing, listings

I am using `listings` with `mathescape=true` to include some typeset output.  However, I would like a little white space around that output.  Currently I have

```
\lstset{language=,
  keepspaces=true,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=flexible,
  mathescape=true,
  }
```

However, the result is that a typeset equation is put on the line immediately following the preceding code, with no vertical white space.

For example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
code: Gimme the square root of two:
$\sqrt{2}$
code: Gimme a rational approximation to pi:
$\displaystyle{\frac{355}{133}}$
\end{lstlisting}
```

comes out as

[image]

I know I could put the equations outside the listing, but it works better for me to have equations escaped within a listing.

How can I force escaped equations to be indented, and have a little white space above and below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert tokens with `escapebegin` and `escapeend`. If you don't use `mathescape` but `escapechar` you can e.g. switch to displaystyle:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}
% #################################################################### COLORS #
\lstset{language=,
  keepspaces=true,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=flexible,
  %mathescape=true,
  escapechar=$,
  escapebegin=\[,
  escapeend=\]
  }  

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
code: Gimme the square root of two:
$\sqrt{2}$
code: Gimme a rational approximation to pi:
$\displaystyle{\frac{355}{133}}$
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also insert some strut:

```
\lstset{language=,
  keepspaces=true,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=flexible,
  mathescape=true,
  escapebegin=\quad\mbox{\rule[-1em]{0pt}{2.5em}},
  }
```

Comment: This makes sense to me - I was confused about the usage of `escapechar`, `escapebegin` and `escapend`, but this example has sorted it out.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=,
  keepspaces=true,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  mathescape=true,
}

\newcommand{\PRESPACE}{\vadjust pre{\vskip\abovedisplayskip}}
\newcommand{\POSTSPACE}{\vadjust{\vskip\belowdisplayskip}}

\newcommand{\DS}{%
  \aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\PRESPACE
  \aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\POSTSPACE
  \displaystyle
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
code: Gimme the square root of two:
$\DS\sqrt{2}$
code: Gimme a rational approximation to pi:
$\DS\frac{355}{133}$
code: OK
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

We have to jump off two groups in order `\vadjust` can act.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a solution which could be generalized; however I've never used `\aftergroup` before!  (I had to look it up to see what it meant.)

Comment: @Alasdair We have to escape the group due to the math formula and also the box made by `listings` around the line.